# Manhua where the female lead rescues the male lead on the condition of being blindfolded

Tags: story-identification, magic, manga

I'm searching for this old manhua (Korean comic) I read about a female lead who was cursed, causing everyone who tries to harm her to die. It starts with a scene where she is chased in the snow by some bad guys who wanna rape her, but she ends up killing them all due to her curse, although she didn't want to.

Then, when she had almost given up on her life, she saw this male lead, wounded, and thought that maybe she could bring a change to her fate by saving a life for the first time, instead of killing again. But she makes sure to blindfold the dude, because she doesn't want the male lead to remember her.

Then as they grow close and as the male lead recovers, she asks the male lead to repay his debt by taking her virginity, as she did not want to be raped by dacoits like last time and end up killing them. But the male lead can be seen crying while doing it, causing the female lead to misunderstand and feel even more worse about her self.

Then the male lead finally recovers (without letting the female lead know, because he knew if he told her she would immediately leave him) and waits for an opportunity to escape (because they were living in a cave of treasure hoarders), so eventually the female lead helps the male lead to run away, as the treasure hoarders were getting angry with him.

Before parting ways, the male lead says he doesn't want to let go of her like this, and asks for permission to at least remove the blindfold so that he could see her face and be able to recognise her when he comes back. But she runs away and returns to her old place, the one she originally ran away from, which was a magical island or something, where she had met the first male lead (or supporting male lead), the blond-haired magic genius who is slightly insane.

I hope this much helps to figure out which manga I'm looking for; if not I can say the rest too about the place she ran back to. Oh, and the female lead here is having a boy cut because she disguised herself as a guy to protect herself from the hoarders' desires. She had long hair in the past though.

Edit 1: I'll be answering the recent question on the fantasy description over here cuz I'm guessing this is where I'm supposed to update it instead of comments? I'm really new to all this so sorry for all the confusion I cause TT

So the magical aspect of the comic starts from this old mythology story that sets place aeons ago.

Once, a really beautiful lady was born,

Amidst the great battle between the golden Angel and the sea serpent. (Yes it's actually angel and not Golden dragon, I remember now )

They say that her beauty was so impressive,that it caused the two to stop their fighting instantly, and they stopped and admired her beauty all day long. But she was so small in front of them, barely the sice of their claws, so they both shape shifted to humans to enjoy beeing with her even more.

They spent centuries together in wooing her I guess, but in the end they told her to choose. The golden Angel said he will let her see what it feels like to soar freely in the sky. The sea serpent said he will show her the might and beauty of the sea. But the girl was conflicted, as she liked them both very much.

Now from here my memory is very jumbled, cuz I'm infamous for not remembering stuff and even jumbling facts , I'm really sorry. So I'll just give a caution that it might not be accurate.

So I don't really remember who she ends up choosing, oh yes maybe she first chooses the golden Angel but then she puts a condition that the angel needs to give up on his powers and wings to love with her. Similarly, the sea serpent too was asked to give up his powers and claws if he wants to be with her.

Since the serpent hesitated, she chose the angel. As the angel was ready to accept that condition, even if the condition killed him from inside.

Seeing the angels stupid decision, the God of angels/ heaven was very angry.oh wait.
Ok now I'm thoroughly confused, as I remember it was the God of angels that put the condition on the angel that he will let him marry that girl only if he gives up on his wings and his right to enter the gates of heaven.

I'm not sure about the wings but I'm pretty sure the God asked the angel to give up on his rights to enter heaven as an angel if he wanted the girl so much. So even if the angel was very upset on having lost so much, he still did not regret it as he was happy he could stay with the woman he loved.

Oh and also I forgot to mention, this angel was the Gods favourite as he was the strongest and brightest among his peers.

The angel and the girl live many years happily together. They even have two kids, a girl and a boy , they are as pretty and golden haired like the angel.

But then tragedy hits.

I don't really remember why or how, but somehow the girl gets kidnapped by this beast bird. The beast bird is known to kidnap people and eat them , or maybe the beast kidnapped woman specifically to eat them, I'm confused as I don't remember.

The thing I'm most confused about is whether the beast kidnapped only girls and impregnated each one of them before killing them after they give birth to his descendants, or was it the case just for the girl specifically.

So like I said, the beast, for some reason that I can't remember, kidnaps the girl, impregnates her, and kills her after she gives birth to his kids( a girl and a boy). Now these kids are like the complete opposite of their half-siblings, these kids have red hair and dark skin. Not that dark but kind of brown skin I guess.

So I'm not sure if the angel ever gets to know weather his wife is dead, but all he knows is that his love has gone missing and he needs to find her no matter what. I'm also not sure if he is aware that she was kidnapped by that beast, but he starts on a very long journey on foot to find her all over the place.

His journey stops only when he realises the scenery has become familiar, as in he came back to the place he started from. His kids are visibly disappointed in their father's unstable behavior.

They plea to him many times to stop this madness and to ask for forgiveness from the God of angels so that they can finally return to heaven or something. But the father denies and still doesn't give up.

Now the details are getting fuzzy in my memory, but somehow the angel puts like a condition with his children, that they need to find their mother (or her descendants,I really have no idea ) and if they fail to do so , only then can they return to heaven.

I'm highly uncertain if that's exactly what he put as the condition,but he did put a condition in front of his children, without completing this they weren't allowed to return. And that condition had something to do with the woman.

So that's how the golden haired descendents try their best to fulfill it so they can return to heaven. And that's how the ferocious red haired powerful clan that lives in the mountains came into existence.

The main male lead of the story also is a descendant of that same red haired clan. He is the chief's son. The second male lead is the descendent of the golden haired people. And he is next in line for the head position.

In that fantasy world,if you want to become the next head (in the magical place where the golden haired guy lives) you need to break a thin twig branch from the magical tree, and use it as a weapon to challenge the current head.

Oh wait maybe that duel is the second way and the first non violent way if through winning people's hearts? I don't remember as the second male lead actually chose the duel, but it could be because the situation at that time demanded him to hurry with it.

So while both parties use a branch of the tree as their weapon, without using any of their powers, to be declared a winner one must thrust the branch inside the opponents heart. That's how the second male lead becomes head.

And only those with the blood of the golden descendants can qualify to challenge the head and take that position. This is one of the many reasons why the second male lead chooses the female lead as his body guard and most trusted person in the world.

It's because he thinks she can cause him no harm fighting for the head position, and this in this cruel world, she was his only heaven where he could relax a little.

But little did he know that the female lead eventually realises that her original hair colour is golden and not brown (brown is just a camouflage colour to hide her true identity) which means she too is a descendant of the golden haired people.

Which means she has full qualification to challenge and kill the second male lead for head position.

Edit two:
Well I've read it as an eng translation by online Korean comic translation sites

that later post their work (or the work just gets copied)

in sites such as manhuatop, zinmanga, coffeemanga, etc.

I don't exactly remember which among those free translation sites I read the manga though, as I keep switching based on translation quality available.

But it's definitely among one of those types of sites and not webtoon (I'm not sure if webtoon has it or not as many of my korean,chinese translated manga I read from sites like those above for free fully)

Also I'm pretty sure that manga isn't that old or anything as it's basically just a manga adaptation of the novel written in Korean, and it must have started around 2019 at least. As I noticed the date of most of the mangas I read is around 2019-2022

Oh and also I thought I should say a bit more detail about her life before running away from the magical island and ending up on the snowy mountains disguised as a boy and traveling with treasure hoarders.

So what happened was, she isn't really a transmigrated soul, just a normal looking brown haired child that got sold by her parents I think (the reason I'm unsure is because my memory is slightly hazy)

So while she was broken from inside after being given up on by her parents, the golden haired dude notices her by asking if she is a young virgin who hasn't had periods or something (I don't exactly remember what terms he put, but it later turns out that the seller was lying about her age or something,so he later gets quite shocked and angry for beeing deceived)

Then the golden haired guy picks her among the many other young girls ahead on his journey to the headquarters of the magic island or something. While they were traveling,the female lead keeps piquing his interest eventually due to her sharp intellect and instincts ,and how mature she is.

This was exactly what the female lead was aiming for too if I'm not wrong, as she has already been abandoned once, she tried her hardest to win the favour of her buyer so that she won't get abandoned again.

Then, when they finally reach the temple (yea I think it was the temple) the girls find out the real reason why they had been brought here before having their first period. It's because these girls will later be used as sacrifices by giving their first night to the current head of the temple in a public performance in front of everyone.

And after that the girl will be killed and offered to their God or something. In order to satisfy the crowd, the head must give a fitting performance of his abilities.

So although the golden haired guy actually brought the female lead as one of the sacrifices, he gradually gets too attached to her later and simply can't bear to let her go be sacrificed in such a vile manner.

He also reasons with himself saying she could be his bodyguard, the only person he could leave his guard around finally,as she had no chance to fight for head position,nor was she opinionated about him.

So what he does is, illegally,he makes her drink a potion he made (it's one of his abilities he is gifted in) and that potion makes her quickly fall asleep. But when she wakes up, she doesn't really find anything wrong with herself at first.

But then she is very worried about not being allowed to meet the golden haired guy anymore, as he visibly starts to distance himself from her to protect her and also to not get so attached to a mere servant anymore.

There is this heartbreaking scene where she ran all the way to his magical tree house at night in scratches, bleeding and cold at night, crying her eyes and throat out for him to come out and not ban her anymore from coming inside to meet him, but he tried his best to not reply but merely saw it with painful eyes through his room glass  Wall.

Then as if in an attempt to soothe her pain, he did a magic to make it look like a gazillion fireflies or something that gave her warmth, energy and protection or something.

She eventually falls asleep and is taken to her room, never allowed to be stepped out again. Then the time finally arrives for girls to dress up and be sent as a sacrifice for the festival.

But the girls need to have met the condition of having finally had their first period to take part in it, and for some weird reason, our female lead does not get her period even though it's time. (yes it's due to the potion the golden haired gave her to grant her an escape from being sacrificed)

But the female lead messes up the plans by using fake blood somehow to show she got periods. It's because that's the only way she could get out and have a chance to meet the golden haired second male lead again.

So she is dressed and brought to walk down the path leading to the bed displayed in public, but later she tries to run away to the golden guys house I think,but she fails, and is eventually pinned down by the old head on the bed. But she survives thanks to a knife she gets her hands on, and thrusts it on the heads chest and runs away causing a commotion.

By now the golden dude has already received news that the girl he tried to protect somehow still ended up getting her periods on time, and so he was on his way to look for her. Thankfully they cross paths, but unfortunately their acts literally speak of treason.

Its because an escaped slave girl meant to be sacrificed just committed treason by not giving her virginity and running away, and the golden dude also became an accomplice by helping her .

So, in a last attempt to make her escape, the golden dude gives her a horse and kisses her suddenly, asking her fiercely to promise to come back to him in three days.

She was already anxious and worried about him, and in love with him, so although she hesitated a lot to split paths with him leaving him to face the danger all alone, she still listened to his advice and ran away from the mess for the time being.

When the golden haired dude saw she has safely backed off from the heat of the fight, he finally faces the current head and challenges him to a fuel on spot, eventually managing to successfully kill him and become the new head. Before this he always used to say he hated the head position, and wants nothing to do with it.

But he knew that if he let things be as it is, knowing he could have changed the situation, he would feel guilty. So he strove to be the head in an order to Remove the tyranny of the current head, full well knowing that the path ahead of him only has misery, betrayal, nights filled with unsurity, suspicion, and filled with zero trust and constant fear of one's life and very lonely.

But he said in order to protect the people he loved,he would happily bear it all with a smiling face.

So back to the female lead who was on her way to a safer place. She somehow trips and falls off the horse due to pursuing arrows, and eventually finds one of the close assistants of the golden haired dude, a girl who helped him in potion making.

She seemed to be dying, and so the female lead, being very attached to the golden haired dude and his acquaintances, she could not leave the girl behind. But the girl said she knew she was dying so it's no use. But it's what she said after that that was the most shocking. She said that the golden haired dude is the real tyrant.
A maniac.

When the female lead did not believe her, she pointed out the fire deal or something placed in the female leads heart as a proof of his insanity as a result of extreme lack of trust and affection deprivation I guess.

The female lead later figures out that the kiss was actually when he placed a fire seal on her heart, meaning that if she did not return this side by three days, her heart and chest will start to burn until she dies in pain and agony.

This scares and shocks the female lead but turns out the girl isn't lying, because she too had a fire seal in her heart, I don't remember who placed it though, the current head or the golden haired dude.

Then the girl tries her best to run away from that place and when it's the third day, just like the girl said, her chest starts to burn a lot. But thankfully, she almost reached the borders.

That's how she crossed into the snowy mountains territories to keep the curse in check so that it doesn't activate as long as she is away from that place.

This is why she never wanted to come back there but later had to. It's because the treasure hoarders she lived with, were actually there to rob the tomb of the red haired main male leads ancestors.

So obviously the male lead never intended to let them leave after he came back in search for the girl.

When the female lead saw how mercilessly he slaughtered the men, her trust in him was shaken, it's because she thought the red haired guy did not even try to recognise if the girl was among them by listening to the voice and searching.

He just straight away started slaughtering ,as if he did not care or knew that she wasn't there. Either case, her trust in him broke too, that's how she decided to run back to the golden haired guy.

Then when she had almost fainted from the heart burn, the golden haired dude finds her on his horseback, and says she took her sweet time to come back to him.

Later the golden haired dude clarifies that he just did not want her to run away from him, and that he was always going to remove the seal if she had returned on time.

But because she proved his fears right,he could no longer immediately Remove the seal.

That's how she gets back to living with the second male lead, as his bodyguard this time. The dude confesses his feelings for her, but seeing how she was in no mood to reciprocate, he respected it and did not probe further.

Every night,she would faithfully guard his bed, and that was the only time when he could finally relax and put his guard down,like a  poor abandoned little child who has no one for him in this world who cares about him.

Then after a few years, the female lead proposes to go on a spy mission to the ice mountain region, where the red haired clan lives.

Some issue had come up which needed some digging to be solved.

That's where I read the comic till.

This comic actually has spoilers in novel updates website.

About what happens after that.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. What colour was the female lead's hair?

Comment: Welcome user153691. It would improve readability if you were to edit in paragraphs as it's somewhat of a "wall-of-text" at present, also the use of whole words rather than abbreviations (fl, ml, coz, tho) would help hugely - especially with our international readership, some of whom are using translation programs that won't recognise what's being said here.

Comment: If anyone correctly identifies this, you can mark their answer as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Comment: Do you recall about what year this old manwha is from? Is it old enough to be a black&white print comic as opposed to a full-color webtoon? Also, manhua refers to Chinese comics, not Korean - is this definitely a Korean manhwa?

Comment: Yep it's defenitely a Korean one cuz it's title and other untranslated parts were in Korean. It's a full on colour comic. And its actually a novel adaptation. The Heroine's hair colour is....brown I guess? It wasn't a colour that stood out like in typical stories. That's because it turns out her real identity was hidden, unknown to even her. Cuz in the later part it shows that the magic stone reacts to her and reveals her true hair colour,that's golden, proving she is a descendant of that golden haired dragon or God ,just like the second male lead.

Comment: So this is still a webtoon. If you can remember when you read it, that would help find it by excluding newer series. Can you go into more detail on this magical island? More details that you can remember would help find this, especially if you can remember stuff that will appear in the first few chapters or in the story synopsis.

Comment: That's a lot of detail, but I'm still not able to find anything from my searches. This might just be old and obscure enough to not have proper tagging. Some more questions; did you read this in French or in English? Do you recall where you read it, e.g. webtoons.com?

Answer (score 2):

This is *[The Golden Forest](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/the-golden-forest)*. It is licensed by Manta; the first 14 chapters are free on their site.

> Don't forget. You owe me a life, and you promised to be mine." Reniae was blessed with the ability to charm men by the goddess Inanna. But for her, it feels more like a curse. After being taken as a slave to the Golden Forest, she flees to the Northland where she finds Kun... and saves his life.

[image: Cover image, from anime-planet]

The cover shows 3 characters as depicted in the question; blonde male lead and red-hair male lead (shading makes it look brown, though). Main character has short brown hair, and is presumably dressed as a bride for the ritual.

The first chapter goes basically exactly as described: the main character is hiding in a cave in snowy mountains with some treasure hunters/grave robbers. One of them discovers that she's a woman and they try to rape her, but all die either from her fighting back or a series of coincidences.

Some of the reviews mention the extensive backstory, which also matches the question.

Found by searching mangaupdates for the tags `Slave/s` and `Based on a Novel`.